# MySQL REGEX in Query Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I have following example array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => TEST1
    [1] => TEST2
    [2] => TEST3
    [3] => TEST4
    [4] => TEST
    ....
)
```

Now in Database values stored as

```
/TEST/IMAGE
/TEST2/VIDEO
/TEST3/MIME
...
```

Now I want to match the substring found in array when to fetch the data from database:

So, I have applied following query:

```
SELECT * FROM media_library WHERE 1 AND sDirectory REGEXP '(/TEST1.*)|(/TEST2.*)|(/TEST3.*)|(/TEST4.*)|(/TEST.*)'
```

But for the syntax `'(/TEST1.*)|`

I have used for loop

```
$data = '';$k=0;
foreach($folders as $key => $val){
    $data .= ($k>0) ? "|" : "";
    $data .= "(/".$val.".*)";
    $k++;
}
```

So, Is there any way to directly use an array which creates format very easily  rather than for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php and after that use `implode()`.

Something like that:

```
$regex = implode('|', array_map(function ($value) {
    return "(/{$value}.*)";
}, $yourarray));
```